# SCD2 in SSIS always see all records as new ones

Tags: ssis, scd2

Here is my issue: I want to build simply ETL process where in Data Flow I'm taking some data from my Staging schema and load them into other place. Also I need to implement SCD2 there. So in theory sounds simply - but SCD component in SSIS always see records as new so every time I'm executing my task it loads same data to my destination table even when there weren't any changes in source data.

In configuration of SCD component I assigned BusinessKey to column data which cannot be changed, I choose rest of dimension column as HistoricaAtributtes, set up start and end dates. Inferred member support is unchecked.

I'm using SSDT 2015 and DB engine is SQL Server 2016

Here is the screen with ETL:

[image: ETL]

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The most important piece of advice you can get here is to ditch the SCD component within SSIS and replace it with something else, such as [this](https://benefic.net/ssis-alternatives-to-the-scd-transform/)

Comment: @iamdave This is a good advice, I changed SCD way to LookUp approach and it works without any problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SCD Advance Editor (<kbd>Right Click</kbd>+<kbd>Show Advanced Editor...</kbd>) and under the Component Properties Tab check for the Custom Properties. Specially take a look on **CurrentRowWhere** and SqlCommand SCD Component Properties. These will let you know why the records having identical Business Keys are determined as new.

Comment: Thank you for this. The project where I face the SCD component problem is already finished with success (it was my first SSIS one). To take care of SCD2 things I used Lookup transformation and MERGE statements in T-Sql.